# Database design question

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 separate objects (A,B) no relationship between A,B

Object A has (X,Y,Z) values

Object B has (X,Y,Z,P,W) values

Values are different in A and B, for example A.Z = 4 while B.Z = 6

What is the best practice in creating tables:

1. Create separate tables (A,B) with values
2. Create table Type (A,B) and Table Value (X,Y,Z,P,W) with key to table Type.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but what's the cardinality of the relationship between instances of Object A and Object B? One-to-one? One-to-many? Many-to-many?

Comment: Anyone who designs a realtional database from an object perspective is doing it incorrectly. Relational databases are not object oriented. You need to understand the relationships between the data and whether they are in a one-one- one to many or many to many realtionship to determine design. What the object are is IRRELEVANT!

Answer (score 2):

For low cardinality and simple situations I would just go with:

`3.` Table AB with columns (X, Y, Z, P, W) and an A/B type identifier and let P, W be null for A objects

With more information I might make a different choice.